# TinyPG doesn't properly parse this grammar, bug or bad grammar?

Tags: c#, parsing, ebnf, tinypg

I need to parse a simple language that I didn't design, so I can't change the language.  I need the results in C#, so I've been using [TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v) because it's so easy to use, and doesn't require external libraries to run the parser.

Things had been going pretty well, until I ran into this construct in the language.  (This is a simplified version, but it does show the problem):

```
EOF               -> @"^\s*$";
[Skip] WHITESPACE -> @"\s+";
LIST              -> "LIST";
END               -> "END";
IDENTIFIER        -> @"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
Expr              -> LIST IDENTIFIER+ END;
Start             -> (Expr)+ EOF;
```

The resulting parser cannot parse this:

```
LIST foo BAR Baz END
```

because it greedily lexes END as an `IDENTIFIER`, instead of properly as the `END` keyword.

So, Here are my questions:

1. Is this grammar ambiguous or wrong for LL(1) parsing?  Or is this a bug in TinyPG?
2. Is there any way to redesign the grammar such that `TinyPG` will properly parse the example line?
3. Are there any other suggestions for a simple parser that outputs code in `C#` and doesn't require additional libraries?  I've looked at `LLLPG` and `ANTLR4`, but found them much more troublesome than `TinyPG`.

Comment: Just as a thought, are you sure that it's `IDENTIFIER` that is at fault of gobbling up `END`, and not `EOF`? In what way doesn't it parse?

Comment: Yes, the error from the parser is:
(1,0): Unexpected token 'EOF' found. Expected END.
And the Parse Tree is lists: IDENTIFIER 'END' as the last thing successfully parsed.

Comment: Does TinyPG support look ahead/ look behind? If so, does changing `IDENTIFIER` to `(?!END\b)\b\w+` fix the problem?

Comment: Huh, that actually worked.  It's not really TingPG that supports that, but the C# regex library it uses, but this worked:
@"(?!END)[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";

I still think this is a bug in in TinyPG (obviously you wouldn't want to have to match all possible keywords this way) but for my particular case, where the only possibly confusion is END, I think this will actually work.  
Thanks!

Comment: I agree, it definitely seems a bug in TinyPG as the solution smells too like a hack to me. There is a fork on GitHub (https://github.com/SickheadGames/TinyPG), but that hasn't been updated for a year as well. I was going to say it might be worth raising an issue there, but assuming you are "jrleek", it looks like you did so already :)

Comment: Yeah, that was me.  I've actually identified the problem area in the generated code, but I'm not 100% sure what the solution is in general. 
As I said, I'm pretty rusty on this stuff.  I think it's either a lexer design bug, or a Reduce/Reduce conflict. In Yacc I think reduce/reduce conflicts are solved by the ordering of the rules, which I think TinyPG doesn't pay much attention to.

Answer (score 0):

You might be the same guy since the issue looks identical, as the one I answered on GitHub, but here it is again for people who google this issue.

Here is an example from the Simple-CIL-compiler project,
The identifier has to catch single words except the ones listed, which means you have to include the exception token's in to the identifier

```
IDENTIFIER-> @"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?<!(^)(end|else|do|while|for|true|false|return|to|incby|global|or|and|not|write|readnum|readstr|call))(?!\w)";
```

Hope that helps.

[(Link to Original post)](https://github.com/SickheadGames/TinyPG/issues/20#issuecomment-240140354)